Mimicking amsart's spacing in itemize
I am using a \documentclass[...]{report} but the spacing between items in \itemize is too large:

I would like the spacing to be like the one in \documentclass[...]{amsart} (page 3 of this document, for example). I looked into amsart's documentation and copied lines [985-995] of page 36 into the preamble of my document. The first problem I encounter is that \endlist is an unrecognized command, and also this:

What should I change? Thank you.

For example, you can use the compactitem environment from the paralist package instead of the itemize environment. Another solution is the enumitem package with the nosep option.

Note that it makes no sense to ask about error messages when you don't provide the code that generates it. My guess is that you are using some code with \@xxx in a name.

In addition to @hair-splitter's comment, I'd probably recommend enumitem over paralist as the latter has not been updated since 2017.

Do you mean amsart or amsbook? There's no amsmath document class.

@egreg Sorry, yes, I meant amsart. I have changed it.

You can use enumitem and issue
\setlist{noitemsep}

which will remove the separation from items.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{noitemsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\item d
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

(I see no reason for report.)


Thank you very much.
